# Counterexamples of dynamical systerms

Tags: dynamical-systems

Please give some counterexamples, some definition could be found here. 
[Eventually periodic point and homeomorphism.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180681/eventually-periodic-point-and-homeomorphism)
[An eventually periodic point must be an asymptotically periodic point?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820254/an-eventually-periodic-point-must-be-an-asymptotically-periodic-point)

1.a recurrent point meanwhile not a transitive point

2.a recurrent point meanwhile not a periodic point

3.a recurrent point meanwhile not a eventually periodic point

I think that a recurrent point is abstract noun, so I need some examples to visualize it in my mind.

Comment: I find your problem statement difficult to follow, and while your other Questions may contain "some definition[s]", it is unreasonable to expect the Reader to go chasing links to find the central definition you want to understand, that of "a recurrent point".  Start by giving a definition of that, and it will pave the way to giving "some counterexamples".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you're talking about topological dynamics, where you have a continuous function $T$ from a space $X$ into itself, and using the following
definitions:

1. A "recurrent point" is a point $p$ such that for every neighbourhood $U$ of $p$, there are infinitely many $n$ such that $T^n(p) \in U$.
2. A "transitive point" is a point $p$ such that for every nonempty open set $A$ there are infinitely many $n$ such that $T^n(p) \in A$.
3. A "periodic point" is a point $p$ such that for some positive integer $n$, $T^n(p) = p$.
4. An "eventually periodic point" is a point $p$ such that there exist positive integers $m < n$ such that $T^m(p) = T^n(p)$.

   An example for all your questions is provided by an irrational rotation of a disk.  Every point is recurrent, but no points are transitive, and no point except the origin is periodic or eventually periodic.